# i want to make a functionality used only X number of times depending on the IP adress

Tags: javascript, java, angular

for exemple if i have a user with an ip adress of 192.198.1.1 he only can use the functionality 5 times then he shoudn't be able to use it again until he sign in to the application. its more like a trial or somthing like that

i have already tried making a database table that save the ip of the user and the number of times he used the functionality but it dosn't seems to be logical solution for me its like allot of database calls and 
could this be done in a better way/solution

the problem isn't about a code but a about a solution actually

Comment: Database approach sounds reasonable for me. But it shouldn't be a seperate request. Instead on serverside do a request-filter, which checks for the request count. It's like an interceptor.

Comment: Another solution is to set a cookie on the client. It's easy to bypass the limit for people with little knowledge of how things works but for many users it could be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Since IP changes pretty frequently I'm not sure that this is the best solution for a trial.
However, you can do it with a DB as you said or with cache (if db is to slow or you don't want to use a DB) and if you're server is stable enough you can even hold this data in memory.

Anyway you can checkout Firebase as a free DB solution if you don't need to save huge amounts of data there

hope it helps :)